# Read data from ISBN API and save in php

Tags: php, isbn

can someone help me how to use ISBN api in php with XML or json to read book details that can be later saved in php variables. Thank you.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to use the ISBN API from http://isbndb.com/api/v2/docs

Choosing between json or xml is part of the api endpoint decription. i.e.

```
http://isbndb.com/api/v2/xml/XXXXXXX/books?q=science&p=3    for xml
http://isbndb.com/api/v2/json/XXXXXXX/books?q=science&p=3   for json
```

and they are simple GET queries with no authentication. Because there is no oAuth token, or body parameters to set, you can use file_get_contents() to do the request. Something like this:

```
<?php
$content =file_get_contents ('http://isbndb.com/api/v2/json/XXXXXXXX/books?q=science&p=3');
$data =JSON.parse ($content) ;
...
```

If you add oAuth / body params, I would have considered using curl, fsockopen, or a library like unirest. But you do not need it there.